# Using sym.renderer.fields with ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro gives NameError: attribute 'fields' not supported on instance of UniqueValueRenderer

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro, nameerror

I have a script that updates the symbology of layers in ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 with Python 3.6:

```
if lyr.name == "Oiling Zone":
    sym = lyr.symbology
    sym.updateRenderer('UniqueValueRenderer')
    sym.renderer.fields = ['ZSURFDOO']
    for grp in sym.renderer.groups:
        for item in grp.items:
            value = item.values[0][0]
            if value == "Heavy":
                item.symbol.color = {'RGB': [250, 52, 17, 100]}
                item.symbol.size = 1.5
                item.label = str(value)
            if value == "Moderate":
                item.symbol.color = {'RGB': [255, 170, 0, 100]}
                item.symbol.size = 1.5
                item.label = str(value)
            if value == "Light":
                item.symbol.color = {'RGB': [255, 255, 0, 100]}
                item.symbol.size = 1.5
                item.label = str(value)

    lyr.symbology = sym
```

This code previously worked, but has started throwing this error on the 4th line:

```
NameError: The attribute 'fields' is not supported on this instance of UniqueValueRenderer.
```

Why am I getting this NameError?

Documentation says fields is an attribute of UniqueValueRenderer.  This is how the layer is displayed in the TOC:

[image: LayerDisplayPhoto]

Comment: I was curious where you referenced ```sym.renderer.fields```? I don't see mention of it in the Pro help docs. I only see ```classificationField```. I'm having trouble setting up a script that uses multiple fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Oiling Zone layer looks like it cannot find its data source because your picture has a red exclamation mark next to it.

If a data source cannot be found for a layer then it will not be possible for ArcPy to find any fields within it.

Comment: You are correct, my code for updating the data source was not working.  I have now updated it with the correct connection properties language, and now the script works.